# Parse mongo db field's value "date" into golang with parse method of time package

Tags: go, datetime-parsing

I've `created_date` column as a string and value of it like `2018-10-04 15:42:19.000404667 +0000 UTC m=+103.387519062` which I got from `mongo` db columns and now I inserted it into `mysql` table and of course it is of `string` type. Now the problem is that I can't parse it and formatted it as well, here I tried with below code to parse but can't get solution.

```
tm, err := time.Parse("2006-02-01", "2018-10-04 15:42:19.000404667 +0000 UTC m=+103.387519062")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

And it printed with some errors like :

> parsing time "2018-10-04 15:42:19.000404667 +0000 UTC m=+103.387519062" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00": cannot parse " 15:42:19.000404667 +0000 UTC m=+103.387519062" as "T"

I tried with different `const` of `time` package but still digging into it, what I'm missing here or am I doing parse with wrong `date` type.

Thanks.

Comment: what does `m=+xxx` mean?

Comment: I got it from `mongo` db column's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the `m=...` part is known to be constant (in which case you should include it in your format string as-is), you will have to strip it from the input string before passing it to `time.Parse()`. There is no way to tell `time.Parse()` that it should ignore a part of the input (except if it is always the same string).

NOTE you should provide a complete time specifier as the format, not just "2006-02-01", because if you don't, the library will extend it in its own way to include hours, minutes and seconds - which isn't necessarily the way you want it (in your case it automatically added `T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00` - but your input data contains a space after the date, not `T`, so it won't match). In your case (judging by your example input data), the format string should be like this: `2006-02-01 15:04:05.000000000 -0700 MST`

Comment: Leo K after removing the `m=...` and applied provided format string its working well, but could we not parse with `m=...` ?

Comment: as I said, `time.Parse()` cannot handle input that contains extra characters - the input **must** look exactly like the format template. There are no 'wildcard' characters. The format should contain either numbers or the string 'MST' that act as placeholders or other literal characters (and anything that isn't a placeholder must appear exactly in the input, otherwise it is seen as invalid).

Comment: Thanks @Leo K , I appreciate for your help.